# Python Regex Query Syntax

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to use a regex to match a certain type of string in a file (an encrypted password). The rules I want to apply for the regex are:

- Contains upper and lowercase characters in any order
- Contains numbers in any location
- Is not a word
- Is not a number

Could someone help me to understand how to do this with the "re" module?

As I test this my approach so far has been something like this:

```
def get_lines( file )
    pattern = r'.*[A-Z]'
    lines = [line.split() for line in file if re.match(pattern, line)]
    return lines
```

So this regex just looks for lines containing a capital letter. That doesn't work because there are a few lines which contain another entirely capitalised field. So, I need to be more specific in identifying those lines which contain the string I'm looking for. I'm not a developer and so don't work with regex patterns very often...

Comment: "Is not a word" can't be defined with a regex... or at least not with any I'd like to look at...

Comment: @d_w_r your question is not related to the python re module but to understanding of regular expressions in general.

Comment: what regular expressions have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not a word" and "is not a number"?

Comment: I've updated the description to show the way I've approached this so far. That has made me realise that reliably trapping the pattern I'm looking for is harder than I first thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on to thg435's answer, the regular expression

```
>>> import re
>>> rx = r'(?:\s|^)(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\s|$))'
```

should find what you're looking for. This gives a result like so:

```
>>> s = "Word NUM123 a8#fc0 ABcd12 0102--212 abC4"
>>> re.findall(rx, s)
['ABcd12', 'abC4']
```

In other words, strings of letters and numbers (separated by spaces) that have at least one digit, one lowercase letter, and one uppercase letter.

Comment: I mean that the string I'm checking against is a mixture of upper & lower case letters and numbers.

Comment: Got it to work with a slight mod. r'(?:\s|^)(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9\\/]+(?=\s|$))'. Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
import re

rx = r'(?:\s|^)(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[a-zA-z])(\S+)'

s = "word 12345 $(#*@!) pass345word pass$(#*@!)word456 just words"

print re.findall(rx, s)
# ['pass345word', 'pass$(#*@!)word456']
```

Explanation:

```
(?:\s|^)         = match a space or a start of input 
(?=\S*\d)        =    (only if it is followed by some non-spaces and a digit
(?=\S*[a-zA-z])  =     and by some non-spaces and a letter)
(\S+)            = then, match a sequence of non-spaces and capture that
```

The lookaheads `(?=...)` serve as boolean predicates to satisfy "at least one letter/digit" requirement.

Comment: This is very helpful. However, I need it to match strings that have uppercase & lowercase characters, not uppercase or lowercase. You've given me a good leg up and I'll see if I can sort the rest out for myself:)